# Sorting a Doctrine ArrayCollection by a specific, custom field

Tags: arrays, symfony, sorting, doctrine, php-7.2

I am attempting to sort an `ArrayCollection` by a specific field. The `ArrayCollection` is an array of courses. In the `Course` entity there is a method called `isLive` which returns a boolean.

I would like to sort this collection to have the "live" courses at the beginning of the array, so that's the courses that return `true` from a `isLive` call.

This is the code I have at present, but the first entry in the `$sorted` array is a non-live course.

```
$iterator = $this->courses->getIterator();
$iterator->uasort(function ($a, $b) {
   if ($a->isLive() == $b->isLive()) {
      return 0;
   }
   return ($a->isLive() < $b->isLive()) ? -1 : 1;
});
$sorted = new ArrayCollection(iterator_to_array($iterator));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got to a solution with the use of `uasort` and `array_search` as below:

```
/**
 * @return ArrayCollection
 */
public function getCoursesSortedByLive(): ArrayCollection
{
    $coursesIterator = $this->courses->getIterator();

    $sortOrder = [true];

    $coursesIterator->uasort(function ($a, $b) use ($sortOrder) {
        return array_search($a->isLive(), $sortOrder) - array_search($b->isLive(), $sortOrder);
    });

    return new ArrayCollection(iterator_to_array($sitesIterator));
}
```

Answer (score 7):

It looks like a good use case for [Doctrine Criteria](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections). They allow to filter/sort ArrayCollections, either in memory if the collection is already loaded, either by adding a `WHERE` / `ORDER BY` SQL clause next time the collection will be loaded from the database. So that's pretty optimized!

Code should look like something like this, assuming you have a `live` field behind `isLive()`:

```php
$criteria = Criteria::create()
    ->orderBy(["live" => Criteria::DESC])
;

$sorted = $this->courses->matching($criteria);
```

Answer (score 4):

For the entity, do this: add an OrderBy annotation to the property.

```
/**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Course")
 * @OrderBy({"live": "ASC"})
 */
private $courses;
```